wordpress dummy image is not showing in dashbord and product
I bought a theme from themeforest. when I m installing the theme dummy is not showing in my product list and even carousel also not working
I tried to change permalink, jetpack uninstall, upload permission 755, media library also not updated

Since this is issue with proprietary theme, it will be hard for the community to provide you with answers.
But creators on ThemeForest, which is run by Envato, provide 6 months of support after purchasing the theme. Please refer to the theme creator’s support team.

This doesn't answer the question and should be a comment
